# Why is my hostname appended to an SSH public key when I generate it from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, ssh-keys

When I generate an SSH key through a Bash file on Ubuntu, the machine name (I guess that's it) of my PC is automatically added to this SSH key.

This is the part that generates the key inside the bash file:

```
# Create new ssh-key
echo | ssh-keygen -P ''

# Cat the ssh-key to print on the screen
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Output: ssh-rsa AAAAB....JpyT+gt pc172@pc172-centre-540S-03ILL
```

Why is this `pc172@pc172-centre-540S-03ILL` part added to the generated key?

That part above is similar to the text that is displayed before the path inside my terminal.

```
c172@pc172-centre-540S-03ILL:/var/www/new-project-ubuntu$
```

Comment: You are talking about the public key and it’s simply a comment to help you more easily identify whose key is whom. When public keys get piled up in an `.ssh/authorized_keys` file it can be an indecipherable pile of ASCII junk. Those comments help you know which key is what. Good for revoking and reviewing access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last part is a comment. Often the comment looks has `username@hostname` in there. This comment part is not mandatory but good practice. From that you know on a server where you put your public key to whom it belongs.

You can change the comment any time in the `id_rsa.pub` file or on any place where you have put it. If you want to specify the comment at key generation use the addition `-C` flag

```
ssh-keygen -C "comment"
```